# Simplifying and improving the unit tests of data type mappers

Tags: java, unit-testing, fixtures, mapstruct

I have written type mappers using Mapstruct to fulfill some common tasks when mapping between entities and DTOs such as renaming properties, "cherry-picking" them by moving them out of a nested structure up to the root level etc. The initial PoC implementation looks as follows:

```
@Mapper(
    componentModel = "spring",
    injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR,
    uses = {DocumentationMapper.class},
    imports = {Kind.class})
public interface ConnectorMapper {
  @Mapping(source = "metadata.extendedProperties", target = "metadata.additionalProperties")
  @Mapping(source = "metadata.documentation", target = "documentation")
  @Mapping(source = "metadata.name", target = "name")
  @Mapping(source = "spec", target = "connectorSpecYaml")
  ConnectorDto fromEntity(final ConnectorYaml connectorYaml);

  @InheritInverseConfiguration
  @Mapping(target = "kind", expression = "java(Kind.Connector)")
  ConnectorYaml fromDto(final ConnectorDto connectorDto);
}
```

This mapper basically does the following:

1. Rename the nested property `metadata.extendedProperties` to `metadata.additionalProperties` and vice-versa.
2. Cherry-pick the nested `metadata.documentation` property for the DTO and apply mapping rules defined in `DocumentationMapper` (via the `uses` clause) and vice-versa.
3. Cherry-pick the nested `metadata.name` property for the DTO and vice-versa.
4. Rename the `spec` property to `connectorSpecYaml` and vice-versa.

In order to unit test this behavior I had to write some crazy assertions that are barely readable anymore:

```
@Test
public void connectorMapperFromEntity() {
  // GIVEN a connector entity with fixed values
  final var connector = FixtureBuilder.createConnectorYaml("connector");

  // WHEN mapping the entity to a DTO
  final var connectorDto = connectorMapper.fromEntity(connector);

  // THEN the mapping yields a result
  assertThat(connectorDto).isNotNull();
  // AND the name has been cherry-picked from metadata into the target
  assertThat(connectorDto.getName()).isEqualTo(connector.getMetadata().getName());
  // AND the metadata has been mapped correctly
  assertThat(connectorDto.getMetadata())
      .isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(connector.getMetadata(), "additionalProperties");
  // AND the extended properties in metadata have been renamed correctly
  assertThat(connectorDto.getMetadata().getAdditionalProperties())
      .isEqualTo(connector.getMetadata().getExtendedProperties());
  // AND the documentation has been cherry-picked into the target
  assertThat(connectorDto.getDocumentation())
      .isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(
          connector.getMetadata().getDocumentation(), "additionalProperties");
  // AND the extended properties in documentation have been renamed correctly
  assertThat(connectorDto.getDocumentation().getAdditionalProperties())
      .isEqualTo(connector.getMetadata().getDocumentation().getExtendedProperties());
  // AND the spec has been mapped correctly
  assertThat(connectorDto.getConnectorSpecYaml()).isEqualTo(connector.getSpec());
}
```

The other direction is equally rough to read due to manually building the DTO from the fixture data:

```
@Test
public void connectorMapperFromDto() {
  final var fixture = FixtureBuilder.createConnectorYaml("connector");
  final var connectorDto =
      ConnectorDto.builder()
          .connectorSpecYaml(fixture.getSpec())
          .metadata(
              MetadataDto.builder()
                  .additionalProperties(fixture.getMetadata().getExtendedProperties())
                  .labels(fixture.getMetadata().getLabels())
                  .build())
          .documentation(
              DocumentationDto.builder()
                  .additionalProperties(
                      fixture.getMetadata().getDocumentation().getExtendedProperties())
                  .exampleUsage(fixture.getMetadata().getDocumentation().getExampleUsage())
                  .longDescription(fixture.getMetadata().getDocumentation().getLongDescription())
                  .shortDescription(
                      fixture.getMetadata().getDocumentation().getShortDescription())
                  .exampleResponse(fixture.getMetadata().getDocumentation().getExampleResponse())
                  .build())
          .name(fixture.getMetadata().getName())
          .build();
  final var connector = connectorMapper.fromDto(connectorDto);
  assertThat(connector).isNotNull();
  assertThat(connector).isEqualTo(fixture);
}
```

At this point I was curious whether there are other approaches to simplify testing the mappers that arent performing simple renaming operations. I was thinking of some way to hardcode the input and expected output objects in JSON rather than building and comparing them manually. Is this a feasible approach or is there something that might be more suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing JSON files containing snapshots in the resources folder that I load during test execution and deserialize using Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is populate your DTO with random test data. Check [here](https://github.com/Blastman/DtoTester/pull/1) how to do this.

Then you could write a test case like this (its a bit pseudocode, but hopefully it conveys my ideas):

```java
@Test
public void testNonNullCases() {

   ConnectorDto controlDto = generateTestData( ConnectorDto.class );

   // map hence-and-forth
   ConnectorYaml resultEntity = connectorMapper.fromDto( controlDto );
   ConnectorDto resultDto = connectorMapper.fromEntity( resultEntity );

   // use assertj to verify them (nested and all)

   assertThat( resultDto )
      .usingRecursiveComparison()
      .ignoringFields( /* fields that you want to do by hand to cover exceptions */
      .isEqualTo( controlDto );

   // do remaining assertions.

}

@Test
public void testNullCases() {

    // I would add a testcase were you leave out attributes (null) and some nested classes in your graph.. just to see whether null cases are handled correctly. You might use jacoco (or other coverage) on the generated code to drive this test

}

public static T generateTestData(Class<T> clz) {
 // get inspiration from https://github.com/Blastman/DtoTester/pull/1
}

}
```